# Unity3D cloud builds iOS and xcode 7

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm working on Unity 5.1.1f1 and using Unity cloud build for iOS with xcode 7 option. My problem is I can't disable App transport Security for my server url, disable bitcode and enable "requires full screen" option on xcode 7. So, game always errors when build.

Any solution is appreciated
Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. It disables BitCode and enable UIRequiresFullScreen.
Tested with XCode 7.3 and Unity 5.4.1p2 version.
Please upgrade to latest version of Unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
#if UNITY_IOS
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
#endif

public class Postprocessor : AssetPostprocessor
{   
#if UNITY_IOS
    [PostProcessBuild]
    public static void OnPostprocessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
    {
        if (buildTarget == BuildTarget.iOS)
        {
            string projPath = path + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";

            PBXProject proj = new PBXProject();
            proj.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(projPath));

            string target = proj.TargetGuidByName("Unity-iPhone");

            proj.SetBuildProperty(target, "ENABLE_BITCODE", "false");

            File.WriteAllText(projPath, proj.WriteToString());



            // Add url schema to plist file
            string plistPath = path + "/Info.plist";
            PlistDocument plist = new PlistDocument();
            plist.ReadFromString(File.ReadAllText(plistPath));

            // Get root
            PlistElementDict rootDict = plist.root;
            rootDict.SetBoolean("UIRequiresFullScreen",true);
            plist.WriteToFile(plistPath);
        }
    }
#endif
}
```